# actors with daemon-style semantics

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, actor

Scala 2.8 was announced yesterday. They highlight among other things ["Enhanced actors"](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/7009).

What does "actors with daemon-style semantics" mean and where can I find more about that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means the same as with daemon threads: A live daemon actor will not keep a system from exiting when 'main' finishes

Answer (score 2):

Right. I was looking for a method in actor, but it's a trait by its own: [DaemonActor](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/scala/actors/DaemonActor.html)